# Strange JavaScript issue with timeout

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I see a developer using this in my site:

```
window.setTimeout("pg.init()", 10);
```

The problem is that when I click once on the record set it works fine. However when I click on the record right away all I get is the hour glass. However if I wait and then click, it works again. What could be wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: More. Context. Please. 
What does pg.init do? Where is this code called from? Is this this clack handler code? Is it all of the click handler code? If not, what is the click handler code?

Comment: pg init initalizes a lot of variables on page load but it has this in top  
pg.init = function(){
 if(pg.tmr){
  window.clearTimeout(pg.tmr);
 }
....
....
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you invoke `pg.init()` without the timeout?

```
pg.init();
```

Alternatively, you could try a lower timeout, but that probably won't make any difference as it's already low:

```
window.setTimeout("pg.init()", 1);
```

Comment: Well here is the thing guys. If I add alert(""); it works just fine..but I dont wanna show the darn ugly alert and make the users to have to click it

Answer (score 0):

Your question hardly makes any sense, but if I were to chance a *guess*, I would say disable the clickable element(s) (or removed the onclick handlers) within the record set once clicked, and add functionality to `pg.init()` which reactivates it/them.